# jQuery .selectable(), Always returns the same ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, jquery-ui-selectable

Below I have this little list:

```
<ul id="selectable">
    <li id='0'></li>
    <li id='1'></li> 
    <li id='2'></li>
    <li id='3'></li>
    <li id='4'></li>
</ul>
<span>You've selected:</span> 
<span id="select-result">none</span>.
```

Combined with jQuery, It *should* get the `id` of the selected element:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
             stop: function() {
                 var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
                 $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                     var index = $( "#selectable li" ).attr( 'id' );
                     result.append( index );
                 });
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Every time, I click an element, it displays: `0`

**Why**? When I click an list-element the second time, it should display: `1` etc, What did I do wrong?

Comment: cant see selectable in your html code

Comment: Can you provide a link to jsFiddle?

Comment: You are getting attribute of the  $( "#selectable li" ) which is the whole collection. Try getting attr of $(this)

Comment: Do NOT start an ID name with a number! http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Comment: @DanielStutz, have you seen w3fools.com?

Comment: @DanielStutz that holds for HTML4, [but not for HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute) anymore.

Comment: @TJonS thx, no.. I am just reading it now ;)

Comment: @DanielStutz, check it out. Good comment (I +1ed it), but don't use w3schools. Use the MDN instead

Comment: @TjonS thank you for the MDN. It's basic to use good and correct documentation (so also a +1).Just checking out w3.org to see, if html5 name convention is different --> moonwave99 is right.

Comment: @DanielStutz, even if html5 is different, I wouldn't use it yet. There is no reason to do something SO UNNECESSARY AND AVOIDABLE as using a number. Glad you like the MDN :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why so difficult? Why not like this:

```
$('#selectable li').on('click', function(){
    // set the value of the clicked li to the result div
    $('#select-result').text( $(this).html() );

    // And optional:
    // set all true's to false:
    $('li[data-selected="true"]').attr('data-selected', 'false');
    // Set the clicked item to true
    $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');
});
```

The optional part is very optional, your question doesnt need it :)

Comment: I was going to use `this.id`, but then realised he might change the html to something like `option 1`, or `blue`. Than he wants that value, not the idea. Same principle for the `.index()`

Comment: i found the bug, just need to change { var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this ); }   TO   { var index = $(this).attr('id'); } working

Answer (score 3):

It's currently collecting the first node within your `$('#selectable li')` as it collects *many* nodes, adjust it to:

`$('#selectable li.ui-selected');`

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyL2Q/1/)**</kbd> - Note, I've adjusted the IDs to `letter + number` [W3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

```
<ul id="selectable">
    <li id='i0'>Zero</li>
    <li id='i1'>One</li>
    <li id='i2'>Two</li>
    <li id='i3'>Three</li>
    <li id='i4'>Four</li>
</ul>
<span>You've selected:</span>  <span id="select-result">none</span>

<script>
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        stop: function () {
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
                var index = $("#selectable li.ui-selected").attr('id');
                result.append(index);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No need to adjust IDs as HTML5 supports numeric IDs.

Comment: @VisioN This I didn't know! =] Thank you, although I think it won't be a habit I'll start anytime soon though

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the solution of MackieeE, since it misses the ability to select multiple items. With the following code this works.

Also on Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CVks3/2/

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
stop: function () {
        var result = $("#select-result").empty();
        $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
            result.append(this.id);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**this might be easier**

```
$('#selectable li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true').siblings('li[data-selected="true"]').attr('data-selected', 'false');
        $('#select-result').text(i);
    });
});
```

Then you don't need the ids at all, and you could target the selected by `$('#selectable li[data-selected="true"]')` or by `$('#selectable li').eq($('#select-result').text())`

**what about deselecting?**

Just going to point out the elephant in the room and say this starts with nothing selected, and may need to be able to revert back.

Something like:

```
$('#selectable li').each(function(i) {//get eq
    $(this).on('click', function() {//on click
        if ($(this).attr('data-selected')==='true') {//if currently selected
            $(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');//unselect    
            $('#select-result').text('none');//no results
        } else {//if not currently selected
            $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true')//mark selected
            .siblings('li[data-selected="true"]').attr('data-selected', 'false');//unselect siblings
            $('#select-result').text(i);//change results
        }
    });
});
```

Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/vm9C2/